# How can i overwrite the summary block in magento2

Tags: magento2, checkout, knockoutjs

I am trying to override the checkout - summary block. I want add custom text after product name. I am not able to find way it is calling and fetching data.

I know it Knockout JS but i am not able to understand it in more detail. Can any tell me what is best way to customize the checkout.

Comment: Have you get your solution?

Answer (score 4):

Hey Bhupendra here answer for you,

You will need to override the template file for summery block using requirejs-config.js(create this file in your module`s view/frontend/requirejs-config.js)

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
             'Magento_Checkout/template/summary/cart-items.html':
          '<Vendor>_<ModuleName>template/summary/cart-items.html'
        }
  }
};
```

up vote if you are satisfied with answer. :)

Comment: thank you for the answer. I already did this but i am not able get option value in this file.I need to set option and if that option found i need display link for popup.Do you have any idea about this ?